# Convert date to other format other than YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: teradata, informatica-powercenter, to-date

I need to convert input date coming in format YYYY-MM-DD. First I convert it into char by following:

**TO_CHAR(<date_column>,'YY/MM/DD')**

then try to convert it into date for this format:

**to_date((TO_CHAR(<date_column>,'YY/MM/DD')),'YY/MM/DD')**

As to_date always converts to default date type of YYYY-MM-DD. What other way can I use to convert this into other format. I am using Informatica Powercenter, so I can not find other function other than TO_DATE.

Comment: A date "format" only applies for transformations to/from a character string. But for a DATE data type, the internal binary form is not visible, while the corresponding "human-readable" display value would be determined by the client.

Answer (score 1):

I think we are ignoring basics - `to_date()` converts to a date format. Now it can be displayed in dd/mm/yyyy depending on setup in your DB client or if you are dumping in a file probably YYYY-MM-DD. And on a date filed you cfan use TO_CHAR o convert it to any format.
So, if your input is a string and is in 'YY/MM/DD' then use `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(imp_yymmdd,'YY/MM/DD'),'DD/MM/YYYY')` - output will be a string of your desired format i.e. DD/MM/YYYY.
If your input is a date then use `TO_CHAR(imp_date,'DD/MM/YYYY')` - output will be a string of your desired format.

Comment: HI thank you for the suggestion, input is in date format, I converted to char in my desired format, till then it is ok. But in target table, the column type is date so I need to convert back to date, when I use TO_DATE( <over_coverted_string_value>) it return default format of YYYY-MM-DD rather than YY/MM/DD (required)

Comment: so, issue resolved ? i always like to pass format. Because you never know what kind of data you are going to receive.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` datatype has no format. You can format a string representing a date.

Assuming your input is `date`, just use `TO_CHAR(yourdate, 'desiredformat')`.

If your input is a `string`, you first need to convert it to `date` then back to `string` again, with the desired format applied. So:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(yourstring, "format-it-comes-in"), "desired-format")
```

Which in your case would be:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(yourstring, "YYYY-MM-DD"), "YY/MM/DD")
```